# How to show last inserted data in create.cshtml page in MVC?

Tags: c#, jquery, sql, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to build a simple school management application where the operator will insert the student's marks along with student id, subject, exam title. Each time the operator insert marks for a single subject on the form I want to show that data on the same page in a table instantly. How can I accomplish that? I tried with the given code below but it gives me an error that says "Value cannot be null.Parameter name: value".

Here is my model

```
 public partial class ExamMark
{
    public System.Guid ID { get; set; }
    public System.Guid StudentId { get; set; }
    public System.Guid SubjectId { get; set; }
    public int Marks { get; set; }
    public string ExamTitle { get; set; }

    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
    public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
  [HttpPost]
    //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public JsonResult Create(string emark)
    {
        bool result = false;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ExamMark em = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExamMark>(emark);
            ExamMark obj = new ExamMark();
            obj.ExamTitle = em.ExamTitle;
            obj.StudentId = em.StudentId;
            obj.SubjectId = em.SubjectId;
            obj.Marks = em.Marks;
            db.ExamMarks.Add(obj);
            db.SaveChanges();
            result = true;
        }
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

View

```
<div class="marksDetails">
<table id="markstable" style="display: none">
    <tr>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <th>Marks</th>
        @*<th>Exam</th>*@
        <th>Operation</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>

    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: We need to see more code, first set up the razor page, the controllers etc... then come back when you're stuck specifically in a specific area

Comment: It would also be nice to see code as text ([formatted as code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)) in the question and not as a picture.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an AJAX call to your database and get the latest records from the relevant table just after a record is inserted.